# How to get response of shell execution

Tags: android, bash, shell, process

All I want to achieve is to get the response from the execution.
For example if I execute command like this "ls"
I want to get string with all the files and directories

For example like this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
```

But I do not know how to get the response.

I run something like this, I thought that I will redirect the output but still nothing

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls",null,new File("/sdcard/myFile") );
```

I tried also something like this but still nothing

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo | ls > /sdcard/myfile");
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
String cmd = "commands";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
String line;
 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()).length() > -1)
 {
  log.append(line);
 }
```

Comment: In above code, `String cmd = "ls /mnt/sdcard";` and
 `log.append(line + "\n");` works great in my case.

Comment: it is okey this but sometimes it throws null exception on this line = bufferedReader.readLine(), can I solve this somehow ?

Comment: Yes, add try catch block and check for response code from **process** like, `p.waitFor();` and `p.exitValue()`. Or check `BuffereReader` first is it **null** or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
try {
     String[] commands = {"dumpstate > /sdcard/log1.txt"};
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh -");
     DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());            
        for (String tmpCmd : commands) {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```